# How to Execute Function after For Loop? - Console Tabs

Tags: visualforce, javascript, tab, console, loop

I am passing primary tab ids iteratively into a function to get the sub tub ids of each primary tab.

At the end of this function I have a list of all primary and sub tabs open. How can I iteratively pass these tab ids to the console page view function?

I would think pageInfoProcess() would invoke after the for loop has completed, but it does not which results in a undefined error when looking for the length. I looked in javascript's .then method, but I ran into the same issue as length with the variable being undefined.

```
<script>

var returnedIds; 
var subTabIds;

function getPrimaryTabIdsFromConsole() {

sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function(result) {
returnedIds = result.ids;

for (let k = 0; k < returnedIds.length; k++) {
    sforce.console.getSubtabIds(returnedIds[k], function (subTabResults) {

            let primaryIdCount = returnedIds.length;
            let primaryIdProcessed = 0;
            console.log('Subtab Ids Returned: ' + subTabResults.ids);
            subTabIds.push(subTabResults.ids);
            console.log('subTabIds after subtab push: ' + subTabIds);
            primaryIdProcessed += 1;


        if (primaryIdProcessed === primaryIdCount) {
            allTabIds = returnedIds.push(subTabIds);
            console.log('allTabIds: ' + allTabIds);
        }

    });
}

});

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All console methods are *asynchronous*, so they have only been enqueued when the `for` loop completes. If you want it to execute after all of the calls have *completed*, you should put the logic in a callback. You will also need to implement some sort of counter to check how many tasks have completed.

```
let completedCount = 0;
let totalCount = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
    sforce.console.doSomeStuff(parameter, function () {
        completedCount += 1;
        if (completedCount === totalCount) {
            // now you are "done with the for loop"
        }
    });
}
```

You may alternatively wish to play around with `window.setTimeout`.

Side note on your JS, please use `const` instead of `var`, except in cases where you assign a value more than once. In the latter case, use `let`. Never use undeclared variables (something you do in your `for` loop).